# why current doesn't flow from separate +&- batteries

Tags: voltage, batteries, current

It might sound simple but I'm new to electronics.
If I connect 2 batteries in series and the voltage adds up then why doesn't the current flow from -&+ of separate batteries. I mean, why do I need to connect the +A and B- (+A-+B- -- couldn't the current just flow from A- to +B)?

Comment: Conservation of charge: Every coulomb that flows in to the "-" terminal must flow out of the "+" terminal and vice versa.

Comment: yes but the terminal separate batteries

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a schematic diagram of the circuit you are asking about?

Comment: it's the b diagram of transistor; he replied to me the last guy

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "the b diagram of transistor". You should include all the information needed to answer your question in the text of your question.

Comment: transistor is the name of the guy who replied to me ,scroll down  2replies to my question & one of them is "@transistor"

Comment: Answers float up and down with votes and user sorting preferences. "Scroll down 2replies" doesn't work on Stack Exchange. Reference by `@username` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Battery terminals are marked '+' and '-' so that you can tell them apart. But the '+' terminal of any given battery is only positive *relatve to* its own '-' terminal, not in any absolute sense. Similarly, the '-' terminal of a different battery is only negative relative to its own '+' terminal.

Current always flows in loops. If you have only one connection to a component (regardless of whether it's a battery or something else), no current can flow.

Comment: what do you mean relative to it's own ,isn't the +, ions & - electrons

Comment: No, it's only electrons. If electrons come out of one end of the battery, then the same number of electrons must go into the other end. The battery as a whole must remain electrically neutral -- no net charge must accumulate.

Comment: so it's the in built battery that is done like this, so it"s due to how the battery is done ,the + &- are kinda linked ; but if there is a high voltage

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKOPsN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Two series connected batteries with a load. Current flows in the circuit. (b) Without a circuit no current can flow. (c) If current could flow in (b) then the cells in a standard torch / flashlight would go flat even though you had switched it off.*

In Figure 1b there is no possible path for current to flow from either battery positive back to its negative.

---

When current flows in a circuit the current out of the positive terminal = current into the negative terminal. The net charge in the battery doesn't change.

---

<... couldn't the current just flow from A- to +B?

Thought experiments:

1. How strong would that current be?
2. What would limit that current to prevent infinite current flowing?
3. What would happen all the charge?